# Can I get an Object from a collection if there's a single Item, but a List<Object> if there are multiple Items?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collections

I'm not sure if this can be done...

I'm trying to create a `Dice` class and a `DiceSet` class in Unity. A `DiceSet` has a `List<Dice>`, but I want a `DiceSet` with one dice to be implicitly equivalent to a `Dice`. **Is there a method or function that returns the item if it's the only item in the list, but still returns the list otherwise?** (Perhaps using Linq, or something)

Currently, there's no inheritance between `Dice` and `DiceSet`, but I'm thinking if I make `Dice` inherit from `DiceSet` and just limit the number of dice in the set to 1, that would do. But, I'm also wondering if there's a better way to do it. I'm concerned that a single `Dice` would count as a `DiceSet` in situations where it shouldn't. Maybe I'm overthinking it.

It would also be nice if, when two `Dice` were added together, they'd make a `DiceSet`. Hmmm... Maybe `DiceSet` should contain a `List<DiceSet>` instead?

**Edit:** Some further information...

I'm trying to make `Dice` parsable from a string (ex. "`3d6+1`" would create a `DiceSet` of three `Dice` with six sides, and with a modifier of +1.

What I'm thinking from your comments, I should forget the "`DiceSet`" concept and just make `Dice` contain a `List<Dice>` itself, and if it only contains one dice, it's still just a `Dice`.

Below is an example of what I'm thinking now.
**Is this thinking correct?**

```
public class Dice : IDice, IRollable, IModifiable
{
    // Set containing quantities for each kind of dice
    public Dictionary<Dice, int> Set { get; set; }

    // implement IDice
    public int NumSides => SideValues.Count;
    public List<int> SideValues { get; private set; }

    // implement IModifiable
    public int Modifier { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedValue => RolledValue + Modifier;

    // implement IRollable
    public int RolledValue { get; protected set; }
    public void Roll() {
        RolledValue = SideValues[Random.Range(0, NumSides + 1)];
    }

    // Dice constructor
    public Dice(int sides = 6, int quantity = 1, int modifier = 0) {
        SideValues = new List<int>(Math.Max(sides, 1));
        for(int i = 1; i < NumSides + 1; i++) {
            SideValues.Add(i);
        }
        Modifier = modifier;
        AddDice(this, quantity);
    }

    // Adds dice to the set
    public void AddDice(Dice dice, int quantity){
        if(Set.ContainsKey(dice))
            Set[dice] += quantity;
        else
            Set.Add(dice, quantity);
    }

    // String conversions
    public override string ToString() {
        // ToDo
    }
    public void FromString(string diceString){
        // ToDo
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have to return a mutable count of elements, you always have to return some kind of enumeration (either IEnumerable, Collection, List, etc.). If the consumer then iterates over the given sequence it could contain zero, one or many elements.

Comment: @Oliver so you're saying no I can't? What about making DiceSet a base class for Dice; would that work for what I'm trying to do, you think? Also, if I'm the only "consumer", is there a hack to make it work how I'd like it to?

Comment: Creating a _DiceSet_ with one dice and then always return a _DiceSet_ seems to fit. As you can see, your set is a wrapper around a collection of dices, so it would be the same as I said.

Comment: So if the `DiceSet` contains a single dice, you want it to be implicitly convertible to a `Dice`? How would you work with that, and how would that be easier than checking the number of dice in a `DiceSet`? Perhaps I'm missing something but it sounds like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @dumetrulo I totally appreciate that. I might be thinking about this totally wrong, but yeah, I initially imagined `DiceSet` as a wrapper for a `List<Dice>`. But, what I think I'm realizing is that I actually need `Dice : DiceSet` and `List<DiceSet>`. Is that correct?

Comment: In my design a `DiceSet` _has_ a collection of `Dice`s, that's it. No inheritance. Maybe the set has some methods or properties to roll all dices or give back the results of all rolls, while a `Dice` has methods or properties to roll herself and give back its own result.

Comment: @Oliver Yeah, that's how I initially implemented my design. They both implement an `IRollable` interface, and when `Roll()` is called on `DiceSet` it calls `Roll()` on each `Dice` in the list. I wanted to be able to add two `Dice` together to make a `DiceSet`, and have `DiceSet` be implicitly castable to `Dice`, but only if it has exactly one. I want to be able to instantiate a new dice with "1d6" and be able to add "1d6+1" to get "2d6+1", or add "1d4-1" to get "1d6 + 1d4 - 1".

Comment: Would a dictionary be more suitable than a list? I could key it by the number of sides on the dice, and have a tuple that contains the quantity and modifier. Then, my `Roll()` method would get a random integer for each key, for each quantity. I'd have to completely overhaul my `Dice` class to make that work though.

Comment: Still don't really get why you need to implicitly cast it to Dice ... why not let both implement said interface and not only have `Roll` but also whatever method/property should be supported by both ... I don't understand your formulas there but it sounds like your `IRollable` could just also have some getter property and the set can handle both the single and multi dice cases

Comment: @derHugo Yeah, I don't know what I was thinking originally. I'm refactoring now. My project has a lot more interfaces and base classes than I described in my question, so modifying them is taking a bit of time. I'll post code soon.

Comment: @Oliver Since you answered my question in your first comment, you can post it. Thank you. If you have any other suggestions or pointers, I'm all ears, but I'll likely have to post a different question if I need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, a method can return only one type. It is also not possible to declare two methods with the same name, same parameters and different return types.

Depending on the scenario, it is sometimes necessary either to return different kinds of the same thing, which can be achieved by returning an interface and using different implementations of it, or to return a different number of elements of the same type (or interface).

The second case fits your problem. Here you should return a collection type. The caller can then check whether the collection has zero, one or many elements and act accordingly. The type of collection to return depends on several factors. Depending on your use case you should consider `IEnumerable<T>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `IReadOnlyList<T>`, `IList<T>`, `ISet<T>` or even a concrete class like `List<T>` or `HashSet<T>`.

Note that especially the interface `IEnumerable<T>` can be evaluated lazily. This can lead to some performance improvements if used wisely, or to worse performance, unintended behaviour or strange effects if used incorrectly.

So, in your specific case, you already seem to have a wrapper for a collection of an arbitrary number of `Dice` called `DiceSet`. This set should *have* a collection of `Dice` and operate on it. In this case it doesn't matter if the set contains one or more dices, the user of the set always executes the methods of the set class or probably iterates over all containing dices and calls a method on them and aggregates the result, where it also doesn't matter if the collection contains one or multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the functionaliy DiceSet should provide, you could use the [Composite pattern C#](https://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern) to make clients working with the DiceSet class unaware of how many Dice are in the DiceSet.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how I might apply this to my project? I read the link you provided and, I'm already doing something similar but, I'm not sure exactly how to achieve what you're suggesting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).